# Extract a value inside a json column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a json column in a pandas dataframe and I need to create a new column based on a value in the json column.

```
case#             json_col

123     [{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': None, 'custom_field_change': None, 'timestamp': '', 'due_date_change': None, 'by': {'email': 'test.com', 'type': 'staff', 'id': 23, 'name': 'test.com'}, 'time_spent': None, 'update_id': 234, 'message': None, 'assignee_change': None, 'status_change': None, 'satisfaction_survey': None},{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': None, 'custom_field_change': None, 'timestamp': '2022-04-18 21:36:00', 'due_date_change': None, 'by': {'type': 'priority', 'name': 'Medium', 'id': 32}, 'time_spent': None, 'update_id': 234, 'message': None, 'assignee_change': None, 'status_change': None, 'satisfaction_survey': None}]
321     [{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': None, 'custom_field_change': None, 'timestamp': '', 'due_date_change': None, 'by': {'email': 'test.com', 'type': 'staff', 'id': 23, 'name': 'test.com'}, 'time_spent': None, 'update_id': 234, 'message': None, 'assignee_change': None, 'status_change': None, 'satisfaction_survey': None},{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': None, 'custom_field_change': None, 'timestamp': '2022-04-18 21:36:00', 'due_date_change': None, 'by': {'type': 'priority', 'name': 'High', 'id': 12}, 'time_spent': None, 'update_id': 234, 'message': None, 'assignee_change': None, 'status_change': None, 'satisfaction_survey': None}]
```

I need to extract the value from the priority  as

```
case#  Priority
 123    Medium
 321    High
```

Edit:
As there are multiple name field in the json, What is the best way to extract name that has type 'priority'

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas build in pd.json_normalize() and limit the column only to the ones that you need

```
import pandas as pd
j = [{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': None, 'custom_field_change': None, 'timestamp': '', 'due_date_change': None, 'by': {'email': 'test.com', 'type': 'staff', 'id': 23, 'name': 'test.com'}, 'time_spent': None, 'update_id': 234, 'message': None, 'assignee_change': None, 'status_change': None, 'satisfaction_survey': None},{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': None, 'custom_field_change': None, 'timestamp': '2022-04-18 21:36:00', 'due_date_change': None, 'by': {'type': 'priority', 'name': 'Medium', 'id': 32}, 'time_spent': None, 'update_id': 234, 'message': None, 'assignee_change': None, 'status_change': None, 'satisfaction_survey': None}]
df = pd.json_normalize(j)
df[['by.name']]
```

Comment: There are many by.name in the same row.  So it provides other data too. Also, this handles only one row. Is there any way we can handle multiple rows.                                   
by.name
0 test.com
1 Medium

Comment: Oh I see the problem now, when you run df = pd.json_normalize(j) of the code above is there anything about it that would indicate that under the 'by.name' column in that row that makes you know you want medium?

Comment: Yes. You are right

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear in the row that contain "medium" in the by.name column is there anything in that row we could use to limit the df to only include that row?

Answer (score 0):

You can try loop the list and extract `name` whose `type` is `priority` then get first item from the output.

```py
df['Priority'] = df['json_col'].apply(lambda lst: next(iter([d['by']['name'] for d in lst if d['by']['type'] == 'priority'])), None)
```

```
print(df)

   case#                                           json_col Priority
0    123  [{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': ...   Medium
1    321  [{'priority_change': None, 'category_change': ...     High
```